# Reading uploaded text file contents in html

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-upload

I want to show contents of uploaded file in html, I can just upload a text file.
My example.html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>

<textarea id="2" name="y" style="width:400px;height:150px;"></textarea>
</html>
```

How can I show contents of any uploaded text file in textarea shown below?
[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371970/read-text-file-using-filereader

Answer (score 86):

I've came here from google and was surprised to see no working example.

#### You can read files with [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) with good [cross-browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader).

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = event => console.log(event.target.result) // desired file content
reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
reader.readAsText(file) // you could also read images and other binaries
```

See fully working example below.

```js
document.getElementById('input-file')
  .addEventListener('change', getFile)

function getFile(event) {
 const input = event.target
  if ('files' in input && input.files.length > 0) {
   placeFileContent(
      document.getElementById('content-target'),
      input.files[0])
  }
}

function placeFileContent(target, file) {
 readFileContent(file).then(content => {
   target.value = content
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}

function readFileContent(file) {
 const reader = new FileReader()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result)
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
    reader.readAsText(file)
  })
}
```

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <label for="input-file">Specify a file:</label><br>
 <input type="file" id="input-file">
</div>

<textarea id="content-target"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I'm trying to upload a file to the server along with some user inputted data using php. So a user selects a file containing some data, then writes some stuff (ie. time, date, serial no.) then clicks upload and it's one file on the server. I think your answer will help me to implement in an alternative way.

Comment: > "a file to the server along with some user inputted data" —
For this task, it seems more natural to use the multipart form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075513/php-parsing-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 32):

Here's one way:

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
    <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
    <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button><td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function loadFileAsText(){
  var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
      var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
      document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
  };

  fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Please note the you do not have any element named _inputTextToSave_ in your html.

Comment: Helped me in a bacbone.js application

Comment: I tried this solution but it fails to compile with the error: ```property result does not exist on type EventTarget``` 
**Note**: I am using typescript

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

**HTML**

```
<p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">
</p>

<textarea id="demo" style="width:400px;height:150px;"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
    var txt = "";
    if ('files' in x) {
        if (x.files.length == 0) {
            txt = "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
                txt += (i+1) + ". file";
                var file = x.files[i];
                if ('name' in file) {
                    txt += "name: " + file.name + "";
                }
                if ('size' in file) {
                    txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes ";
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (x.value == "") {
            txt += "Select one or more files.";
        } else {
            txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
            txt  += "The path of the selected file: " + x.value; // If the browser does not support the files property, it will return the path of the selected file instead. 
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4z6wv6hf/1/)**

Comment: This  works  but wrongly. It gives property of file not content of file(if file.txt contains "2 3 4 " It should give "2 3 4").

Comment: Output does not answer the question, it gives the file type and the file size

Comment: Does not answer the question, which sought to read file content.

Comment: question is for reading file content not file information or filesize.. your code is not giving file content