# How to read a csv file on angular2 line by line

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, csv

I am programming an application in angular2 that reads a csv file with a simply input in html:

```
<input type='file' name='userFile' id='file' >
```

I can access to the file at the component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {

   var input = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("file"));
   input.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      var files = input.files;
      var len = files.length;

         if (len) {
          console.log("Filename: " + files[0].name);
          console.log("Type: " + files[0].type);
          console.log("Size: " + files[0].size + " bytes");
    
         }

      }, false);

}
```

How can I read cell by cell a csv file uploaded using typescript, JavaScript or jQuery? (and which is the best way to do it).

Comment: You're not attaching the event in angular way. You should not directly access the dom using dom api. You can check the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746837/reading-uploaded-text-file-contents-in-html

Comment: What is the correct way to do it on typescript/angular? I am newie.

Comment: Where should I place the event function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a example implementation angular way (Angular version 2+):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-file',
  template: `
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelect($event.target)" name="myfile">
   </div>
  `,
  styles: [``]
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

    csvContent: string;
    
    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(){
    }

    onFileLoad(fileLoadedEvent) {
            const textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;              
            this.csvContent = textFromFileLoaded;     
            // alert(this.csvContent);
    }

    onFileSelect(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    
      const files = input.files;
      var content = this.csvContent;    
      if (files && files.length) {
         /*
          console.log("Filename: " + files[0].name);
          console.log("Type: " + files[0].type);
          console.log("Size: " + files[0].size + " bytes");
          */
          
          const fileToRead = files[0];
          
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload = this.onFileLoad;

          fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
      }
              
    }
}
```

[Try it on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ueqog)

Comment: Thank you for the example. I will use the reader outside implementations at a function as at the example.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. But I'm having an issue inside the onFileLoad function: when I pass in a method in the outer class the debugger says that the "this" is bound to the FileReader class...

Answer (score 12):

In addition to [asmmahmud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46745059/1016343), I'd like to add how you can actually parse the file content so you have rows and columns in an array  (Angular with TypeScript). Add the property:

```
parsedCsv: string[][];
```

to the class  `YourComponent` in his example.
Then, update the `onFileLoad` event as follows:

```
onFileLoad(fileLoadedEvent): void {
 const csvSeparator = ';';
 const textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
 this.csvContent = textFromFileLoaded;
 // alert(textFromFileLoaded);

 const txt = textFromFileLoaded;
 const csv = [];
 const lines = txt.split('\n');
 lines.forEach(element => {
   const cols: string[] = element.split(csvSeparator);
   csv.push(cols);
 });
 this.parsedCsv = csv;
 // console.log(this.parsedCsv);
}
```

Now you have the parsed CSV with its lines and columns in the two-dimensional array `parsedCsv` (1st dimension is the rows, 2nd dimension the column). You can replace the separator if required - default is semicolon.

**Example:**

A file containing

> A;B;C
>   
>  1;2,300;3
>   
>  4;5.5;6

produces the following data structure in `parsedCsv`

[image: ExampleContent]

You can see that if your file contains column headers, then the data starts with row index 1, otherwise (without column headers) with row index 0.

[Updated Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztb3tj)

**Note:** On Stackblitz, I have added the following few lines so you can see how the array is populated:

```
  // demo output as alert
  var output: string="";
  csv.forEach(row => {
    output += "\n";
    var colNo = 0;
    row.forEach(col => {
      if (colNo>0) output += " | ";
      output += col;
      colNo++;
    });
  });
  alert(output);
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. But I'm having an issue inside the onFileLoad function: when I pass in a method in the outer class the debugger says that the "this" is bound to the FileReader class...

Comment: @user545871 - can you create the issue you have as a stackblitz example? That makes it easier to understand and resolve it.

Answer (score 4):

```
csv2Array(fileInput: any){
//read file from input
this.fileReaded = fileInput.target.files[0];

let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(this.fileReaded);

reader.onload = (e) => {
  let csv: string = reader.result;
  let allTextLines = csv.split(/\r|\n|\r/);
  let headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
  let lines = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
    // split content based on comma
    let data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    if (data.length === headers.length) {
      let tarr = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        tarr.push(data[j]);
      }

      // log each row to see output 
      console.log(tarr);
      lines.push(tarr);
    }
  }
  // all rows in the csv file 
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", lines);
} }
```

Comment: ty for the example. csv.split(/\r|\n|\r/); makes from my csv file an extra empty value at each row. I also see split(',') can make me troubles, as I am at Europe, and we write 19,456 for a float number at an excel file. This migth be solved making the correspondant replace(",",".") before it.

Comment: to handle error Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.....
do type casting
const csv: string = reader.result as string;

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to extract the text:

```
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e) {
      var text = fr.result;
      console.log(text);
    };
    fr.readAsText(files[0]);
```

And then using split separate rows and cells into arrays:

```
var rows = text.split("\n");
console.log("Row 0 " + rows[0]);
console.log("Row 1 " + rows[1]);
console.log("Row 2 " + rows[2]);
var row1 = rows[0].split(";");
console.log("Value 0,0 " + row1[0]);
console.log("Value 0,1 " + row1[1]);
console.log("Value 0,2 " + row1[2]);
```

*This code doesn't work well if cells contain ";" characters, wich is not the case of my application.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function as a Promise

```
  /**
   * Returns the CSV file content as a string.
   * New lines are separated by '\n' inside the string.
   * @param file 
   */
  public async readCSVFile(file: File): Promise<string | ArrayBuffer> {
    return new Promise<string | ArrayBuffer>((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = e => {
        return resolve((e.target as FileReader).result);
      };
      reader.onerror = e => {
        console.error(`FileReader failed on file ${file.name}.`);
        return reject(null);
      };

      if (!file) {
        console.error('No file to read.');
        return reject(null);
      }
      reader.readAsText(file);
    });
  }
```

You can use it like this

```
this.readCSVFile(myCsvFile).then((fileContents) => {
      //fileContents --> CSV file content as a string
 });
```

And, if you are fighting with spanish characters like ñ, this worked for me

```
reader.readAsText(file, 'ISO-8859-3');
```