# Vue.js read input file type .txt

Tags: file, text, input, vue.js

I am using vue cli v.2.5.2

Would like to read the contents of a text file.

The form,

```
<input type="file" @change="onFileChange()">
```

calls the method onFileChange()

```
  onFileChange: function(e){
        this.someData = e.target.files[0].result;
        console.log(this.someData);
      },
```

someData is declared in data,

```
data(){
      return {
          someData: ''
      }
    },
```

There are many examples online but they nearly all involve uploading an image file. I am trying to read an uploaded text file.

Would FileReader() be useful here?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746837/reading-uploaded-text-file-contents-in-html