# Upload text file and make JavaScript variable that text

Tags: javascript, html, upload

I am trying to make a text file reader for a library I am making.

It returns the path. How can I make it to return the contents of a file?

```js
function alertText() {
    var text = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    alert(text)
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="alertText();">
```

Thank you.

Comment: should be duplicated,check [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading uploaded text file contents in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746837/reading-uploaded-text-file-contents-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below function, it will give you file content in "fileContent" variable:

```
function alertText() {
  var file = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

  var reader = new FileReader(); 
  reader.onload = function (evt) {  //When file is loaded.
    var fileContent = evt.target.result; //event.target.result is the file content     
  }
  reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: chrome dev tools say that parameter 1 is not a type of blob. what should I do?

Comment: var file = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].files[0];  Use this, it will work.