# How to load a text file into a textbox in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a Javascript compiler, first of all I want to load the ***text.txt*** by opening a File Dialog and load this into my Textbox. I've found some documentation on the internet how to achieve this but most of these contents teaches you by saving the file into your server. I'm looking how to just load the text file and paste or show into a Textbox.

This is my code which I have achieved so far:

**Model**

```
    public class CargarArchivo
    {
        public string file { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index( HttpPostedFileBase File)
    {
        CargarArchivo archivo = new CargarArchivo();

        return View(archivo);
    }
```

**View**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.file, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file" } })

    <input type="submit" value="upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

I have no idea what is `HttpPostedFileBase` for, I just followed this on the documentation. Code works **OK** and just open a file dialog.

I have tried this, but didn't work:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index( string File)
    {
        var cont = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(File);
        CargarArchivo archivo = new CargarArchivo();
        archivo.File = cont;

        return View(archivo);
    }
```

Comment: If the file resides on the user's computer see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746837/reading-uploaded-text-file-contents-in-html

Comment: If the file resides on he user's computer means I should use JS? Good idea, but I thought ASP.NET MVC could handle this *client side* load.

Comment: ASP.NET is server-side processing. You'd need to upload the file to the server before you can leverage that API then return the rendered view to the browser. All of that is unnecessary if you don't need to store the file server-side then return a completed form back to the user.

Comment: do you want select file and display content immediately?

Comment: That's right Hien, but I got this by typing some JS code, thanks to Jasen.