# How to convert Base64 String to javascript file object like as from file input form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file, base64

I want to convert Base64String extracted from file(ex: "AAAAA....~") to a javascript file object.

The javascript file object what I mean is like this code:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="selectFile" >
```

JS:

```
$('#selectFile').on('change', function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];

  console.log(file)
}
```

'file' variable is a javascript file object. So I want to convert a base64 string to the javascript file object like that.

I just want to get file object by decoding base64 string (encoded by other app from a file) without html file input form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

**Way 1:** only works for dataURL, not for other types of url.

```js
function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','),
        mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[arr.length - 1]), 
        n = bstr.length, 
        u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
}

//Usage example:
var file = dataURLtoFile('data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8=','hello.txt');
console.log(file);
```

**Way 2:** works for any type of url, (http url, dataURL, blobURL, etc...)

```js
// return a promise that resolves with a File instance
function urltoFile(url, filename, mimeType){
    if (url.startsWith('data:')) {
        var arr = url.split(','),
            mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
            bstr = atob(arr[arr.length - 1]), 
            n = bstr.length, 
            u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
        while(n--){
            u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }
        var file = new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime || mimeType});
        return Promise.resolve(file);
    }
    return fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
        .then(buf => new File([buf], filename,{type:mimeType}));
}

//Usage example:
urltoFile('data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8=', 'hello.txt','text/plain')
.then(function(file){ console.log(file);});
```

Comment: Warning, it seems to me that File object is only available on Firefox. Prefer Blob objects : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: I use your **2nd way ** to upload pdf thumbnail but, it display black image when upload is done

Comment: @ChetanBuddh That may be caused by other issues of your code. Can you paste your code in JSFiddle ?

Comment: In way 1, i am getting [object Object] not [object file]. How can i get [object file].@cuixiping

Comment: May i get your assistance please @cuixiping

Comment: @TeChn4K Use Blob instead of File for older browsers which doesn't support File as contructor.

Comment: @EdukondaluThaviti You can paste your code into jsfiddle and paste the link to me.

Comment: This does not work for the file of format `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQA` Could you please let me know if this can be doable? @cuixiping

Comment: @Pavan I tried your case and didn't find any exception. Maybe your browser is too old? you can take a look at the console.

Comment: option#1 worked for me. I am converting Image to base64 to compress the image and converting it back to image (file object) and sending it to backend server to store in amazon s3. Thanks for the code snippet.

Comment: @coderpc It works well for your example. Maybe your code has other issues.

Comment: @cuixiping I tired in my ionic angular application. in bowser it working fine but in my apk build it not working. "lastModified":null, "lastModifiedDate": null, "size": 0,

Comment: I'm getting 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large) when using fetch with base64 image strings, maybe because they are longggg...

Comment: Please use dataURLtoFile instead of fetch if the dataURL is long.

Answer (score 115):

```
const url = 'data:image/png;base6....';
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const file = new File([blob], "File name",{ type: "image/png" })
  })
```

Base64 String -> Blob -> File.

Comment: Note: This is incompatible with most Content Security Policies, if you have one

Comment: @MaxGabriel could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you have a CSP with the connect-src attribute to whitelist what URLs your Javascript can load, it will reject it with the error: "Refused to connect to 'data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src <...>". You can have your CSP whitelist data URLs, but MDN warns: "This is insecure; an attacker can also inject arbitrary data: URIs. Use this sparingly and definitely not for scripts." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src

Answer (score 69):

This is the latest `async/await` pattern solution.

```
export async function dataUrlToFile(dataUrl: string, fileName: string): Promise<File> {

    const res: Response = await fetch(dataUrl);
    const blob: Blob = await res.blob();
    return new File([blob], fileName, { type: 'image/png' });
}
```

Comment: You can get the file type from the base64 url: `dataUrl.match(/^data:(.+);base64/)?.[1]`

Comment: And don't write `Response` and `Blob` types. TS will infer them

Comment: The only answer that worked for me. In Vue JS I used this code: 



async dataUrlToFile(dataUrl, fileName){

      let res = await fetch(dataUrl)
      const blob = await res.blob()
      return new File([blob], fileName, { type: 'image/png' })
    }

Answer (score 7):

Here is the Typescript version of accepted answer above by @cuixiping, now using Buffer instead of atob()

I saw deprecation warnings using atob() from TypeScript, although it isn't fully deprecated. Only one overload is. However, I converted mine to use the deprecation warning suggestion of Buffer. It seems more clean since it requires no extra loop to convert each character.

```
  /***
   * Converts a dataUrl base64 image string into a File byte array
   * dataUrl example:
   * data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIsAAACLCAYAAABRGWr/AAAAAXNSR0IA...etc
   */
  dataUrlToFile(dataUrl: string, filename: string): File | undefined {
    const arr = dataUrl.split(',');
    if (arr.length < 2) { return undefined; }
    const mimeArr = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/);
    if (!mimeArr || mimeArr.length < 2) { return undefined; }
    const mime = mimeArr[1];
    const buff = Buffer.from(arr[1], 'base64');
    return new File([buff], filename, {type:mime});
  }
```

at the top of the file you'll need an import to make the typings happy.

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
```

No special npm packages are needed.

Comment: Still works lovely on September 13th 2023. Thank you!
If you already have your parsed base64 string, you can just use:
const buff = Buffer.from(yourBase64StringContent, "base64");
const fetchedFile = new File([buff], yourDesiredFileName);

Answer (score 7):

```
const file = new File([
  new Blob(["decoded_base64_String"])
], "output_file_name");
```

You could use a lib like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-arraybuffer) to decode and encode base64 to arrayBuffer.

Comment: It didn't work for me!

Comment: works for browser (thanks), does not work for react native (Error: Creating blobs from 'ArrayBuffer' and 'ArrayBufferView' are not supported)

Comment: for react-native i use the form data method

Answer (score 5):

```
const base64Str = "AAABAAEAICAAAAAAAACoCAAAFg....AND_SO_ON";
const file = new File(
   [Uint8Array.from(atob(base64Str), (m) => m.codePointAt(0))],
   'myfilename.jpeg',
   { type: "image/jpeg" }
);
```

Comment: This needs some context that explains why it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar requirement (importing a base64 encoded image from an external xml import file.  After using [xml2json-light library](https://github.com/enkidoo-ai/xml2json) to convert to a json object, I was able to leverage insight from cuixiping's answer above to convert the incoming b64 encoded image to a file object.

```
const imgName = incomingImage['FileName'];
const imgExt = imgName.split('.').pop();
let mimeType = 'image/png';
if (imgExt.toLowerCase() !== 'png') {
    mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
}
const imgB64 = incomingImage['_@ttribute'];
const bstr = atob(imgB64);
let n = bstr.length;
const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
while (n--) {
  u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
}
const file = new File([u8arr], imgName, {type: mimeType});
```

My incoming json object had two properties after conversion by xml2json-light: FileName and _@ttribute (which was b64 image data contained in the body of the incoming element.) I needed to generate the mime-type based on the incoming FileName extension. Once I had all the pieces extracted/referenced from the json object, it was a simple task (using cuixiping's supplied code reference) to generate the new File object which was completely compatible with my existing classes that expected a file object generated from the browser  element.

Hope this helps connects the dots for others.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up,

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
   function readMtlAtClient(){

       mtlFileContent = '';

       var mtlFile = document.getElementById('mtlFileInput').files[0];
       var readerMTL = new FileReader();

       // Closure to capture the file information.
       readerMTL.onload = (function(reader) {
           return function() {
               mtlFileContent = reader.result;
               mtlFileContent = mtlFileContent.replace('data:;base64,', '');
               mtlFileContent = window.atob(mtlFileContent);

           };
       })(readerMTL);

       readerMTL.readAsDataURL(mtlFile);
   }
</script>
```

HTML

```
    <input class="FullWidth" type="file" name="mtlFileInput" value="" id="mtlFileInput" 
onchange="readMtlAtClient()" accept=".mtl"/>
```

Then mtlFileContent  has your text as a decoded string !

Answer (score 0):

***Complete Version for Typescript***

```
async uploadImage(b64img: string) {
  var file = await this.urltoFile(b64img,'name.png',this.base64MimeType(b64img));
}

//return a promise that resolves with a File instance
urltoFile(url, filename, mimeType){
    return (fetch(url)
        .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
        .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], filename,{type:mimeType});})
    );
}

//return mime Type of bs64
base64MimeType(encoded) {
    var result = null;
  
    if (typeof encoded !== 'string') {
      return result;
    }
  
    var mime = encoded.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/);
  
    if (mime && mime.length) {
      result = mime[1];
    }
  
    return result;
}
```

***Thats Work for me Converting base64 Image to File***

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me [**credit**](https://github.com/mudassirmaqbool/Resize-And-Compress-Image-In-JavaScrip)

```
base64ToFile = (url: string) => {
let arr = url.split(',');
// console.log(arr)
let mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)![1];
let data = arr[1];

let dataStr = atob(data);
let n = dataStr.length;
let dataArr = new Uint8Array(n);

while (n--) {
  dataArr[n] = dataStr.charCodeAt(n);
}

let file = new File([dataArr], 'File.png', { type: mime });

return file;
};
```