# Why do some values get removed after refresh when using redux persist?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I am keeping track of some files that are going to be uploaded to S3.

I've added redux persist to persist the redux state even after refresh.

Why would some of the file object's values get removed after refresh?

The original object in redux (which is actually part of a bigger object... [{person:{}, files:[file:{}]}] )
looks like this:

```
{
  file: {
    name:"test.png"
    preview:"blob:http://localhost:8080/..."
    size:39545
    type:"image/png"
  }, 
  progress: 100, 
  uploader: S3Upload, 
  completed: true, 
  url: "...test.png"
}
```

after I refresh the object looks like this:

```
{
  file: {
    preview:"blob:http://localhost:8080/..."
  }, 
  progress: 100, 
  uploader: {…}, 
  completed: true, 
  url: "...test.png"
}
```

Why is name, size, and type not present in the second file object?

Comment: How exactly do you store the file data to redux in the first place?

Comment: I was having the same issue, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41228383/1952668) helped me resolve the issue.