# Turn a blob url into a upload file for FormData() and send it via AJAX to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to convert a blob URL AKA (window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);) into a file object so I can use it with FormData() so I can use that as an upload image file for AJAX but I am not able to do that successfully and I can't find a way to make the blob URL into a file

object for my code situation and I know its possible to do this according to the posts I visited on here it can be done here's one of posts that claim that you can do that [How to convert Base64 String to javascript file object like as from file input form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940290/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-javascript-file-object-like-as-from-file-input-f?noredirect=1&lq=1) but the reason why I'm not using any of those posts methods because I don't know how to integrate their methods to my code situation or its too complicated to understand.

This is my code that I been working on.

**index.php**

```
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

document.querySelector('#image-input').addEventListener('change',createABlobUrlForAImgSrcAndUseThatAsAFileUploadFile);

function createABlobUrlForAImgSrcAndUseThatAsAFileUploadFile(){

//Creating a blob URL

var image_input = document.querySelector('#image-input').files[0];

var file_type= image_input.type;

var blob = new Blob([image_input], { type: file_type || 'application/*'});

var blob_url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); //<-Example blob:http://localhost/ed6761d2-2bb4-4f97-a6d8-a35c84621ba5

//

//Form data
var formData= new FormData();

formData.append('blob_url', blob_url);
//

//<AJAX>
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange= function(){

if(xhr.readyState == 4){

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML= xhr.responseText;

//<Allow JS in AJAX request>
var exJS= document.querySelectorAll('#output script');
var enableAll= exJS.length;
for(var i=0; i < enableAll.length; i++){
eval(exJS[i].text);
}
//</Allow JS in AJAX request>

}
}

xhr.open('POST','x');
xhr.send(formData);
//</AJAX>
}

});

</script>

<input id='image-input' type='file'>

<div id='output'></div>
```

**x.php**

```
<?php

$file=$_FILES['blob_url']['name'];
$location='images/'.$file;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['blob_url']['tmp_name'],$location);  

?>
```

I know my code is not logically correct and I will have to change my code to be able to do what I want to do so I am aware it is not logically correct. Just trying to show you guys what I mean.

Comment: @user9375528 have you got any solution?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I got it done in my project. But in my case, I wanted to convert a blob to a wav file and then send to the back-end.

```
//Save your blob into a variable
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

//Now convert the blob to a wav file or whatever the type you want
var wavefilefromblob = new File([blob], 'filename.wav');

//Pass the converted file to the backend/service
sendWavFiletoServer(wavefilefromblob);

//This is my function where I call the backend service to send the wav file in Form data
function sendWavFiletoServer(wavFile) {
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file", wavFile); 
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "https://yourserviceurl/api/");
  ajax.setRequestHeader('API_SECRET', UzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyLCJleHAiO');
  ajax.send(formdata); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply and example I don't think your understanding what I want to do exactly I basically plan to use the blob urls in p tags for example like this <p id='a1'>blob:localhost/ed6761d2-2bb4-4f97-a6d8-a35c84621ba5</p> and then get that blob urls from the p tag and covert it to a upload because I know a blob url is not a blob it's just a reference to a blob I just want to use the blob url that reference to a blob as a file input file I hope you know what I mean now . Use blob urls and get which blob url belong to what blob and convert it to a file input

Comment: document.querySelector('#a1).innerHTML; and convert the blob url to make a reference to its blob and convert it to a file upload

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and found a way.

This will give you a Blob object:

```
let blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
```

Comment: While this is _probably_ slower / less-efficient than the examples where you are handling the blob in one code block, this works for me in my stack using React / Redux where I may have a component that handles picking the image and, another component further up the tree that handles uploading the image - Redux complains about File objects being `non-serializable`

Answer (score 1):

I think uploading form data should be a blob object, not a blob URL

javascrip:

```
var image_input = document.querySelector('#image-input').files[0];
var blob_url= window.URL.createObjectURL(image_input); 
//Form data
var formData= new FormData();
// ...

// here , content-type: multipart/form-data
formData.append('upload_file', image_input);
```

php:

```
$file=$_FILES['upload_file']['name'];
$location='images/'.$file;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'],$location);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feed back i'm not asking to send a blob url I basically want to convert the blob url on the client side into a file because I know that a blob url is just a reference to a blob because I plan to have blob urls on the page and then I want to get them like this for example <p id='a1'>blob:http://localhost/ed6761d2-2bb4-4f97-a6d8-a35c84621ba5</p> and then use JS like this document.querySelector('#a1').innerHTML; and then convert it to a file upload because I know a blob url is just a reference to a blob I hope you understand what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I use below code and it worked for me

```js
var fileFromBlob = new File([videoFile], 'uidVideo.mp4');

// Create new form data
const form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fileFromBlob);
    

//custom function for call api
const { statusCode } = await apiCallFn('POST', form, routes.uidVideo, false, true);
console.log(statusCode);
    
    
/////////////////////// api call function that come in the top code
export const apiCallFn = async (method, data, url, agent, type) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // build config
  let config = {
    method,
    url,
    data,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': type ? 'multipart/form-data' : 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer' + ' ' + accessToken,
      accept: 'application/json',
    },
  };

  if (agent) {
    config['headers']['agent'] = agent;
  }

  // Call axios function to get or post data
  try {
    const { data } = await axios(config);
    // console.log("data", response.data);
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  } catch (error) {
    // const { statusCode } = error.response.data;
    // console.log(error.response.data);
    console.log(error.response.data);
    return Promise.resolve(error.response.data);
  }
};
```