# Vuetify v-file-input set files in javascript vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Following scenarion:

User fills out form which includes `v-file-input`. The files attached are also sent to server and saved there. User has option to `edit` the form. All the fields of the form are filled with the saved data. How can I fill the `v-file-input` field with dynamically with the saved files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your server will need to base64 convert your files for this solution. Note: Client = the Vue application.

1. Client requests file data in base64 format from the server (RESTful Endpoint or other means, your choice). This should be done in a `created` hook, and assigned to a data property (I'll use `myFileBase64` as an example).
2. Client has a computed property `myFileAsFile` that calls the below function ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940290/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-javascript-file-object-like-as-from-file-input-f)) to convert `myFileBase64` from base64 to type `File`:

```js
 function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {

        var arr = dataurl.split(','),
            mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
            bstr = atob(arr[1]), 
            n = bstr.length, 
            u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

        while(n--){
            u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }

        return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
    }

    //Usage example:
    var file = dataURLtoFile('data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=','hello.txt');
    console.log(file);
```

3. Client sets the value of the `v-input` to `myFileAsFile`. This can be done via `v-bind:value`

Here is a Codepen demonstrating the assignment part of my answer: https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/OJVxvYY