# Base64 to Gallery plugin not work in Ionic 4 and 5

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugins, ionic5

Plugin is ::

- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-base64-to-gallery
- npm install @ionic-native/base64-to-gallery

When I saved a image into gallery then show this error “Error while saving image”

Code ::

```
downloadQR(){  
const canvas = document.querySelector(‘canvas’) as HTMLCanvasElement;  
const imageData = canvas.toDataURL(‘image/jpeg’).toString()  
console.log(imageData)  
let data = imageData.split(’,’)[1];  
console.log(data)  
this.base64.base64ToGallery(data, {  
prefix:’_img’,mediaScanner : true}).then(async res=>{  
console.log(res)  
let toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({  
header : ‘QR code save’  
})  
toast.present()  
}, err => console.log(“err”,err)  
)  
}
```

What is problem of my code? any other solution ??

Comment: do you have gallery access permission? check your Permission settings.

Comment: yes I give android permission. I used this plugin .ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
npm install @ionic-native/android-permissions

Comment: As per Plugin Documentation This Plugin is Deprecated and no longer works. Your have to try different approach.

Comment: Which plugin you say? permission plugin or base64-to-gallery plugin?

Comment: base64 to gallery

Comment: Do you know any other plugin same as base64 to gallery???

Comment: use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file Plugin to save your file. but for this you have to write little extra code to convert your base64 to file.

Comment: check this to convert your base64 to file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47497249/5909026

Comment: I follow this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/save-base64-encoded-image-to-specific-filepath/96180/9 solution same as your solution. but image is saved and not show in gallery. after app is uninstall then image was remove. so do you have any other solution to save image ?

Comment: Hello @NajamUsSaqib I solve this problem with use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-library this plugin. This is save image in gallery.