# What is the format of the URL from google image search results? And how to save the image with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, url, fetch

When I search images on google and select `copy image address` from the right-click menu, the address isn't a conventional `https://...` one. In fact it's a massive string that begins with `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...`. What is this? Also how do I use this image to save it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

The URL is a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). You can save it to a file as per [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38935990/11664580):

```js
 function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
 
        var arr = dataurl.split(','),
            mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
            bstr = atob(arr[1]), 
            n = bstr.length, 
            u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
            
        while(n--){
            u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }
        
        return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
    }
    
    //Usage example:
    var file = dataURLtoFile('data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=','hello.txt');
    console.log(file);
```