# How to upload Base64 data to a server using formdata React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise, multipartform-data

I have an image in Base64 format. I want to send it to the API using formdata. How can that be achieved? I am using React native signature canvas to get the Base64 of the signature.

```js
let signature = base64signature;
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('attachments', {
  uri: signature,
  name: 'logo',
  filename: 'logo',
  type: 'image/png',
});
```

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940290/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-javascript-file-object-like-as-from-file-input-f) as well but don't understand how to send it to the API as formdata. It's constantly giving network errors.

I have also tried to convert it to a blob and send but that didn't work either. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you add the code that you tried?

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: No, the code that transforms the base64-encoded string to a `File` object. Please also include the error message(s) in your question

Comment: The object you're appending to your `formData` isn't any of the [acceptable parameter types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#parameters). It must be be _"a `USVString` or `Blob` (including subclasses such as `File`)"_

Answer (score 1):

```
var imgBase64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCA..." //your bse64 image

onSubmit(){
const file = DataURIToBlob(imgBase64)
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('upload', file, 'image.jpg') 
formData.append('profile_id', this.profile_id) //other param
formData.append('path', 'temp/') //other param
}

    function DataURIToBlob(dataURI: string) {
        const splitDataURI = dataURI.split(',')
        const byteString = splitDataURI[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0 ? atob(splitDataURI[1]) : decodeURI(splitDataURI[1])
        const mimeString = splitDataURI[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

        const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length)
        for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)

        return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString })
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way without external libraries.

```js
let signature = base64signature;

const formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append('attachments', {
  uri: signature, // base64
  name: 'logo.png',
  type: 'image/png',
});

await axios.post('/', formdata, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to install `react-native-fs`

```js
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

  const createTempImage = async base64String => {
    try {

      let base64 = base64String.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
      const fileName = `${Date.now()}.png`;
      
      const path = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`;
      await RNFS.writeFile(path, base64, 'base64');
      
      const image = {
        uri: Platform.OS == 'ios'? path: 'file://' + path,
        name: fileName,
        type: 'image/png',
      };

     return image
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).