# I can't upload an image to firebase, i keep getting an error (task.on is not a funtion),

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, base64, firebase-storage

1. Upload was successful in the console.

```
const sendPost = () => {
  const id = uuid();
  const storage = getStorage();
  const storageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${id}`)
  const uploadTask = uploadString(storageRef, cameraImage, "data_url").then((snapshot) => {
    console.log('Uploaded a data_url string')
  });
}
```

2. uploadTask.on is not a function (console error). I am trying to monitor the progress of the upload

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
  const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  console.log("Upload is" + progress + "% done");
  switch (snapshot.state) {
    case "paused":
      console.log("upload is runnig")
      break;
  }
})
```

3. trying to logout errors, if any

```
(error) => {
  switch (error.code) {
    case "storage/unauthorized":
      break;

    case "storage/canceled":
      break;

    case "storage/unknown":
      break;
  }
},
```

4. Trying to get the uploaded file URL and post it as a doc to firebase db

```
() => {
  getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
    addDoc(collection(db, "posts"), {
      imageUrl: URL,
      username: "swizz6ix",
      read: false,
      profilePic: user.profilePic,
      timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    })
    navigate("/chats")
  })
}, );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`uploadString()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#uploadstring), the upload is not resumable. If you want to track upload progress then you'll have to use [`uploadBytesResumable()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#uploadbytesresumable) that takes a `Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer` as parameter and not a `base64` string. So first you'll have to convert the `base64` string into a Blob.

Checkout: [How to convert Base64 String to javascript file object like as from file input form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47497249/13130697)

```
const fileToUpload = parseFileFromBase64();

const task = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, fileToUpload)

task.on(...)
```