# Display a view of a base64 text file in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, base64

I have a base64 of a .txt file and I want to display it in React. The file looks like this:

```
ID:948201
name:"someText"
description:".txt"
base64File:"QU5URSBQVVBBQ0lDIEtSQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFMSg=="
```

Can I display the text of the document, which is "ANTE PUPACIC KRAAAAAAAAAAALJ", somehow on the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can decode base64 using `atob()`:

```html
<div id="text"></div>

<script>
  let data = {
    "ID":948201,
    "name":"someText",
    "description":".txt",
    "base64File":"QU5URSBQVVBBQ0lDIEtSQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFMSg=="
  }

  let decodedText = atob(data.base64File);
  document.getElementById("text").innerText = decodedText;
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can turn the base64 to a `File` and then use `FileReader` API to read the `File` as a text.

```js
function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {

  var arr = dataurl.split(','),
    mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
    bstr = atob(arr[1]),
    n = bstr.length,
    u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

  while (n--) {
    u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
  }

  return new File([u8arr], filename, {
    type: mime
  });
}


//Usage example:
var file = dataURLtoFile('data:text/plain;base64,QU5URSBQVVBBQ0lDIEtSQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFMSg==', 'hello.txt');
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.readAsText(file);
fr.onload = function() {
  console.log(fr.result);
};
```

References.

[Turn base64 to file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38935990/11887902)

[Use FileReader API to read the file text.](https://linuxhint.com/read-local-text-file-javascript/#b2)

Comment: I like your solution, but how do I display it in react with jsx? Using div, input?

Comment: @OmarLittle Thanks, if you want to display the text, then create a `state` for that text, and then the `setState` once you parse the file, and show the `state` in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea in which format you may want to convert your file, I hope following link may help you :
https://forums.meteor.com/t/base64-convert-back-to-file/34188

Comment: I want to display the text of the file on my React page

Comment: following link might helpful : https://github.com/rpsankar001/base64topdf/blob/master/index.js#L3