# Blob generated from base64-encoded png image within FormData instance recognized as application/octet-stream on server-side

Tags: javascript, base64, blob, multipartform-data, mime-types

Okay so I have a correctly, base64-encoded png image, that I convert into a Blob as such:

```
const match = imgBase64String.match(/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/);

if (!match) {

    throw new Error("Failed to decode base64-string.");

}

const imageSuffix = match[1];
const base64StringWithoutPrefix = imgBase64String.replace(
    /^data:image\/\w+;base64,/,
    ''
);
const imgAsBinaryString = atob(base64StringWithoutPrefix);

const blob = new Blob(
    [imgAsBinaryString],
    {type: `image/${imageSuffix}`}
);
```

I then append this data into a FormData instance, together with an additional key-value pair, like so:

```
const formDataPayload = new FormData();
formDataPayload.append(
    'img',
    blob,
    `img.${imageSuffix}`
);

formDayaPayload.append(
    'key',
    'value'
);
```

I then submit the instance using:

```
fetch(
    'https://example.org/my-endpoint',
    {
        method : 'POST',
        mode   : 'same-origin',
        cache  : 'no-cache',
        body: formDataPayload
    }
);
```

The dev tools show that the request is sent correctly as `multipart/form-data` request, with the according boundary, and the `type` property of the `blob` is correctly `image/png`. The `Content-Type` of the `img` property of the `multipart/form-data` payload is also `image/png` in the dev tools when inspecting the sent request. The problem is that the receiving server always still detects the upload `img` file as having the type `application/octet-stream`.

How can I assure that the MIME-type the server perceives is indeed `image/png`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure the server correctly recognizes the MIME type of your uploaded file, you should convert the base64 string to a `Uint8Array` before creating the `Blob`.

```
function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
    var binaryString = atob(base64);
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes;
}

const match = imgBase64String.match(/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/);

if (!match) {
    throw new Error("Failed to decode base64-string.");
}

const imageSuffix = match[1];
const base64StringWithoutPrefix = imgBase64String.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
const uint8Array = base64ToUint8Array(base64StringWithoutPrefix);

const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], {type: `image/${imageSuffix}`});

const formDataPayload = new FormData();
formDataPayload.append('img', blob, `img.${imageSuffix}`);
formDataPayload.append('key', 'value');

fetch('https://example.org/my-endpoint', {
    method : 'POST',
    mode   : 'same-origin',
    cache  : 'no-cache',
    body: formDataPayload
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah okay, I though it was due to the problem that I did not convert it into a `File` instance (see my answer below, which worked!). Could you may explain the reason for the Uint8Array being the reason under the hood? Thanks in any case!

Comment: When you use atob to decode a base64 string, it returns a binary string, which is not suitable for representing binary data as it interprets the data as UTF-16 encoded text. A Uint8Array is used to correctly represent the binary data, where each element is a single byte of data. By converting the base64 string to a Uint8Array, you preserve the correct binary representation of your image data. This approach maintains the correct MIME type when the data is encapsulated in a Blob object and sent to the server. Using Uint8Array helps in correctly preserving the MIME type during data transmission.

Comment: Cheers, accepted your answer to thank you for your effort!:)

Answer (score 1):

After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940290/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-javascript-file-object-like-as-from-file-input-f), I found a working solution if I convert the base64-string to a BLOB and then in turn that BLOB into a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) instance.

With the risk coming with fetching dataURLs in your applications mentioned in the comments of the linked question, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl) to generate the BLOB from your base64-string without relying on `fetch` in a way which in the end leads to the proper mime-type recognition on the server-side.