Persisting blob in Pinia
I need a little help using pinia-plugin-persistedstate.
I am trying to persist my store where I am saving files downloaded from S3
here is my store:
export const useScanStore = defineStore('scans', {
    state: () => {
      return {
        scanList: [] as ScanInfo[],
      }
    },
    getters:{
      getScan:(state) => {
        return (id: string) => {
          return state.scanList.find(scan => scan.id === id);
        }
      }
    },
    actions: {
      addScan(id: string, file: File){
        this.scanList.push({id, file})
      }
    },
    persist:true,
  })
  
  interface ScanInfo {
    id: string
    file: File
  }

After refresh, I get a hit in the store (getScan returns a Scan object). However, the file seems to be missing (I get a A Proxy with an empty target)
Any help appreciated. Thanks

I didn't use s3 on client side myself. Is this about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File or something else? In case it is, t needs to be serialized and deserialized in order to be stored. Store base64 https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272491/3731501 . Then convert it back to File if you have to like https://stackoverflow.com/a/70634472/3731501 , though this may add inconveniences if you need file data as the result

Blobs can get big, so I suggest using the indexedDB as local- and sessionStorage are limited to few MBs. Unfortunately pinia-plugin-persiststate only support sync storages excluding indexedDB. So you have to do it yourself, my approach would be a setup Pinia Store and on certain points, down- or upload, you use the indexedDB to store your blobs.
