# How can I turn a .csv list into an option list using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I have a .csv list with names separated with semicolons: `John Smith;Ola Nordmann;` etc, and I was wondering how I can read the file and then print out the names like this:

```
<select>
  <option> John Smith
  <option> Ola Nordmann
  <option> etc
<\select>
```

It’s a local csv file and I have to use vanilla JavaScript.

My thought was that I could use a for-loop and somehow count the semicolons to determine the for-loops length, but I don’t really know how to do that. Nor do I know how get the data “out” of the file and “into” the option list.

Comment: Use can use `split(';')` on the string to get an array of names. As to how to read a file try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12372727 if you if will supplying the file from browser

Comment: I assume you mean "csv", as in "character-separated value"? CVS is either a pharmacy or a source-control system, depending on context.

Comment: @Viney what if it's from a local file?